# Neo4J - Match on all relationships between two nodes except for specific relationship

Tags: neo4j, match, relationship

I have two nodes, A and B, linked by several relationships, r1, and r2.

I want to match on `(A)-[r1]-(B)`, but not `(A)-[r2]-(B)`.

How can I achieve this in a query?

```
MATCH (a)-[r]-(b)
WHERE NOT r = r2
RETURN a
```

Comment: So you want to find nodes connected to other nodes by any relationship at all *except for* a specific relationship type?

Comment: Are `A` and `B` [node labels](https://neo4j.com/docs/getting-started/3.5/graphdb-concepts/#graphdb-labels) or just node instances? And are `r1` and `r2` [relationship types](https://neo4j.com/docs/getting-started/3.5/graphdb-concepts/#graphdb-labels) or just relationship instances?

Answer (score 0):

You can get all the relationships except `r2`:

```
MATCH (a)-[r]-(b)
WHERE NOT ((a)-[:r2]-(b))
RETURN a
```

Alternattly, You can also match with relationship type as follows:

```
MATCH (a)-[r]-(b)
WHERE NOT type(r) ="r2"
RETURN a
```